# Cutting a polygons into smaller squares in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, pyqgis, polygon, clip

In order to analize a GeoTIFF image we'd like to cut a huge polygon feature from a `shapefile` into smaller chunks (this is because for some reason our analysis is not performed well with a polygon with a huge extent).

What exactly we want to obtain is to for a given polygon **P**, **window_width** and **window_height** we want to get a list of polygon features where every feature is a intersection of a **P** with a set of disjoint, adjacent windows which has a shape of a rectangular with **window_width** and **window_height**.

This picture shows what we mean:

[image: An example on how we want our algorithm to work]

For this polygon we'd like to get a list of 12 new polygon features where first is a triangle, second - a pentagon, third - a square and so on.

What is important that we want to have this as a `Python` function. So we'd like to have the following function:

```
cut_polygon_into_windows(p, window_height, window_width)
```

to be add to our API.

Comment: do you have access to arcpy libraries? This could be done with a fishnet and an intersection.

Comment: No - and it was stated that this solution should be written using open source packages.

Comment: It would be better if you say this in the question

Comment: I'm working on a solution with PyQGIS. Is your `p` polygon already loaded in the canvas or you load it directly from an external source?

Comment: We are loading it from a source file (shp file).

Comment: GIS SE is not a coding service.  Not only do you need to post what you want, you need to post what you've tried. Coding questions here are expected to contain a good faith effort to solve the problem. See the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) for posting guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution starts from the preliminary creation of a grid (as a memory layer) which covers the extent of your input shapefile: for doing this, I adapted a code taken from this [blog](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/11/26/how-to-generate-a-vector-grid-of-polygons-in-qgis-using-python/).

Once the grid is created, I intersect each feature of it with the input layer.

Starting from this sample shapefile:

[image]

and using this code (I formatted it as a function, even if isn't very efficient to group all these lines together):

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant

def cut_polygon_into_windows(p, window_height, window_width):

    crs = p.crs().toWkt()
    extent = p.extent()
    (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax) = (extent.xMinimum(), extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMinimum(), extent.yMaximum())

    # Create the grid layer
    vector_grid = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs='+ crs, 'vector_grid' , 'memory')
    prov = vector_grid.dataProvider()

    # Create the grid layer
    output = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs='+ crs, 'output' , 'memory')
    outprov = output.dataProvider()

    # Add ids and coordinates fields
    fields = QgsFields()
    fields.append(QgsField('ID', QVariant.Int, '', 10, 0))
    outprov.addAttributes(fields)

    # Generate the features for the vector grid
    id = 0
    y = ymax
    while y >= ymin:
        x = xmin
        while x <= xmax:
            point1 = QgsPoint(x, y)
            point2 = QgsPoint(x + window_width, y)
            point3 = QgsPoint(x + window_width, y - window_height)
            point4 = QgsPoint(x, y - window_height)
            vertices = [point1, point2, point3, point4] # Vertices of the polygon for the current id
            inAttr = [id]
            feat = QgsFeature()
            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry().fromPolygon([vertices])) # Set geometry for the current id
            feat.setAttributes(inAttr) # Set attributes for the current id
            prov.addFeatures([feat])
            x = x + window_width
            id += 1
        y = y - window_height

    index = QgsSpatialIndex() # Spatial index
    for ft in vector_grid.getFeatures():
        index.insertFeature(ft)

    for feat in p.getFeatures():
        geom = feat.geometry()
        idsList = index.intersects(geom.boundingBox())
        for gridfeat in vector_grid.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids(idsList)):
            tmp_geom = QgsGeometry(gridfeat.geometry())
            tmp_attrs = gridfeat.attributes()
            if geom.intersects(tmp_geom):
                int = QgsGeometry(geom.intersection(tmp_geom))
                outfeat = QgsFeature()
                outfeat.setGeometry(int)
                outfeat.setAttributes(tmp_attrs)
                outprov.addFeatures([outfeat])

    output.updateFields()

    return output


# Load the layer
p = QgsVectorLayer('C:/path_to_your_file/input.shp', 'display name', 'ogr')

# Set width and height as you want
window_width = 300
window_height = 300

# Run the function
output = cut_polygon_into_windows(p, window_height, window_width)

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([output])
```

I obtain the desired result:

[image]

Comment: +1, I just implemented a similar function using your code example into my plugin (previously it called processing but I wanted to avoid it) so thanks :)